# Upserting one single nested object inside an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, upsert

What I need to do is to either update the counters inside the only one nested object or insert the entire doc containing the array with init'd counters.

Example of doc:

```
{
  "_id":{"$oid":"61f020f40e2f03f0b93b69f1"},
  "v":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "list":[{"p":{"$oid":"61f020f40e2f03f0b93b69f0"},"c":1,"hom":0,"het":1}]
}
```

**All the docs will have for sure a "list" array with at least and at most one nested object.** And the pair `(v,list.p)` is unique.

So, starting from a previous find, for each element of the cursor, I'm calling the upsert function in js, which actually finds the doc, then inserts or updates the collection whether it is found.

```
function upsert(doc){
    _hom = doc.field1.field2 == "hom" ? 1 : 0;
    _het = doc.field1.field2 == "het" ? 1 : 0;
    filter = {"v": doc.anId, "list.p" : "61f020f40e2f03f0b93b69f0"};
    project = {"list.c":1, "list.hom":1, "list.het":1, "_id":0};
    res = db.collection.find(filter, project);
    if(!res.hasNext()){
        doc = {"v": doc.anId, "list" : [{"p" : "61f020f40e2f03f0b93b69f0", "c" : 1, "hom" : _hom, "het" : _het}]}
        db.collection.insertOne(doc)        
    } else {
        list = res.next().list[0];
        _c = list.c + 1;
        _hom += list.hom;
        _het += list.het;
        update = {$set : {"list" : [{"p" : "61f020f40e2f03f0b93b69f0", "c" : _c, "hom" : _hom, "het" : _het}]}}
        db.collection.updateOne(filter, update)
    }   
}
```

So imagine something like :

```
db.anotherCollection.find({...},{...}).forEach(doc => upsert(doc))
```

It does work, but it's pretty slow. Is there any other way to do this? I read online that upserting an array to do something like this is not possible, cause you either need to  push, pull, based on query, ecc... But I need to update existing counters of a nested object, if doc is found, or rather insert an entire doc, if doc is not found.

Mongo 4.4.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this can't really be done in a singe db call, you could however simplify the code and reduce the average amount of db calls done in total.

Specifically speaking you we can instead of `find -> update` just execute an update, if the update is "successful" then we can just return, otherwise we insert. This means whenever the `list` already exists you have a redundant `find` query that is not needed.

Here is the code:

```
function upsert(doc){
    _hom = doc.field1.field2 == "hom" ? 1 : 0;
    _het = doc.field1.field2 == "het" ? 1 : 0;
    filter = {"v": doc.anId, "list.p" : "61f020f40e2f03f0b93b69f0"};
    update = {$inc : {"list.$.c": 1}}
    updateRes = db.collection.updateOne(filter, update)
    if(updateRes.matchedCount == 0){
        doc = {"v": doc.anId, "list" : [{"p" : "61f020f40e2f03f0b93b69f0", "c" : 1, "hom" : _hom, "het" : _het}]}
        db.collection.insertOne(doc)
    }
}
```

Now the amount of improved performance is dependent on your "hit" rate, I would assume for most processes it should be high which means it'll be significant. The performances for "misses" is not affected as the update "acts" the same as a find if no matching document exists.

Comment: It actually improves a lot, time almost halved. You helped me! thanks :)